# How to fix it Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, mutators

Why when I use query builder instead there is an error on the function diffForHumans (), but if I use ELoquent ROM but no error there is a way to overcome it? (How can i fix it) thank you

[diffForHumans()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvsXD.png)

this is **ArticlesController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Article;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use DB;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $articles =DB::table('articles')->get();
        $articles = ['articles'=>$articles];
        return view('articles.index',$articles);
    }
}
```

this is model **Article.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Article extends Model
{
    //
    use SoftDeletes ;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','content','live','post_on',
    ];

    protected $dates =[
        'post_on','deleted_at','created_at','updated_at',
    ];

    public function setLiveAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['live'] = (boolean)($value);
    }

    public function getShortContentAttribute()
    {
        return substr($this->content,0,random_int(60,150))."...";
    }

    public function setPostOnAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['post_on'] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }

    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['post_on'] = Carbon::parse($value);
    }



}
```

and that is my code, how i can fix it? 
thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

i noticed a couple of things in you're code,

- no need to cast `created_at` and `updated_at` to dates, they are already casted and are instances of `Carbon`
- you can use the property `$casts` to cast simple attributs like `live`
- no need to add a mutator for `post_on` date because you add it to `$dates`
- also you set a mutator on `created_at` instead of `post_on`, you use `SetCreatedAttribute` instead of `setPostOnAttribute`
- instead of `substr($this->content,0,random_int(60,150))."..."` you can use `str_limit` helper function of Laravel, also change `random_int` to `rand` => `int rand ( int $min , int $max )`

the query builder return `dates` as strings, you need to parse before using them or you will get an error like this one `PHP error:  Call to a member function on string`, just do it like this :

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse(\DB::table('articles')->first()->post_on)->diffForHumans()
```

you can make your model simpler like this :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Article extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes ;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id','content','live','post_on',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'post_on','deleted_at'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'live'  => 'boolean'
    ];

    public function getShortContentAttribute()
    {
        return str_limit($this->content, rand(60,150));
    }
}
```

also you can simplify you `index` method like this :

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = DB::table('articles')->get();

    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

Comment: ouh thank you this is good suggestion, and when i try your suggestions it works

Answer (score 7):

By default eloquent returns `date/time` fields as a `Carbon` instance, where query builder don't. So if you want to use `Carbon` on query builder's returned property, you have to wrap the property with `Carbon::parse()` method.

For example, I can use one of `Carbon`'s method `toCookieString()` on a eloquent result such as

```
echo App\User::find(1)->created_at->toCookieString();
```

which will give a response like this `Thursday, 10-Aug-2017 17:59:53 UTC`. But if I use query builder instead such as

```
echo DB::table('users')->find(1)->created_at->toCookieString();
```

then it will give an error

> Call to a member function toCookieString() on string

To use `Carbon` in here I have wrap the property with `Carbon`'s `parse()` method.

```
echo Carbon\Carbon::parse(DB::table('users')->find(1)->created_at)->toCookieString();
```

This will give the desired result as eloquent.